# Android smartphone watch (smart watch) that can record calls

Tags: audio, smartphones, smart-device, audio-recording, smartwatch

I need to record my phone calls.  Don't worry, it's legal in my jurisdiction for the calls I make.

Google has made it more and more difficult to record calls with Android smartphones in recent years.

I've been tempted to switch back to a non-Google "dumbphone" just to get the ability to easily record calls again.

But, before I do, I was wondering: **Are there are any Android-compatible smart watches that allow one to record calls?**

Comment: If there were, you would have to use the watch for the calls, like a spy.  One way is to put it on speaker and record on another device.

Comment: But although that solution works it's not clean

Comment: @RohitGupta If required to record calls, I am okay using the watch for the calls if the speaker and microphone are adequate.